# Fastestest way of calculating Running Totals in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, cumulative-sum

I want to calculate the running total in each line of my select query so that I can filter the rows that get returned based on that total. The way I see it I have only 2 options.

1. Use `over` in select statement and make the main query a subquery

Example:

```
SELECT DocDate,
       Debit,
       RunningTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT T1.DocDate,
           T1.Debit,
           SUM(T1.Debit) OVER(ORDER BY T1.DocDate DESC) AS RunningTotal
        FROM Invoices T1
) AS T
WHERE RunningTotal < @CurrentBalance
```

2. `Join` table with itself

Example:

```
SELECT T1.DocDate,
       T1.Debit,
       SUM(T2.Debit) AS RunningTotal
FROM Invoices T1
JOIN Invoices T2 ON T1.DocDate <= T2.DocDate
GROUP BY T1.DocDate,
   T1.Debit
   HAVING SUM(T2.Debit) < @CurrentBalance
ORDER BY T1.DocDate DESC
```

Both queries return exactly the same result. Performance wise though, what would be the suggested way to go?

Comment: In general, window functions are going to be faster than more complicated approaches.

Comment: @i_ll_be_back - SQL isn't executed directly, it's taken and an "execution plan" is formed; much like compiling code.  In fact in comparing, for example, C to SQL; C is Imperative, and SQL is Declarative, which means the database engine has much wider range of options in terms of How it implements your Declared functional requirement.  So, in short, writing nested queries doesn't Necessarily result in that many iterations across the data; it's just a mechanism for expressing functionality.  But joining the data the way described usually Does incur the expressed overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your table has so few rows that you can count them on one hand, the built-in window function is going to be faster.

Why?  First, it is built-in and designed for this purpose.

Second, it actually calculates a cumulative sum.  So, when calculating the 10th value, it is using the result from the 9th cumulative sum and just adding one more value to it.

The `join` approach is a particularly egregious way of doing the calculation.  If you have 100 rows in the table, then it expands the table to 100 * 99 / 2 rows (give or take) -- and then has to aggregate way more than 100 rows.  You can see that this just gets worse as your table gets bigger.

That said, if you have three rows in the table, you might find that the join works better.  Such is the law of larger numbers:  sometimes surprising things happen on smaller numbers.

Comment: Great explanation! My table contains thousands of rows so I guess over and subquery is the way to go.